# Adding tinyMCE editor in Shiny modal

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, tinymce

I'd like to create an HTML editor in a Shiny app, using the `shinyMCE` package.

This works well in the example below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMCE)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  header = dashboardHeader(disable = T),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tags$script(src = "http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js",
                referrerpolicy = "origin"),

    tinyMCE("editor", "The content"),
    actionButton("ok", "OK")
    ))

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  observeEvent(
    input$ok,
    {
    print(input$editor)
    }
  )

  observeEvent(
    input$open,
    {
      showModal(myModal())
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server = server)
```

Indeed, if you press OK, the content of the editor is printed in the R console.

Now, I'd like to put the editor in a modal. If I do the following the editor appears, but if I press OK the content doesn't get updated. That is, the R console always shows "the content", independently of what is written in the textarea.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMCE)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  header = dashboardHeader(disable = T),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tags$script(src = "http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js",
                referrerpolicy = "origin"),

    flowLayout (
      actionButton("open", "Open")
      )))

myModal <- function()
  {
  modalDialog(size = "l",
              title = "A modal dialog",
              tinyMCE("tinyTxt", "the content"),
              actionButton("ok", "OK"),
              easyClose = T)
  }

server <- function(input, output, session)
  {
  observeEvent(
    input$ok,
      {
      print(input$tinyTxt)
      }
    )

observeEvent(
    input$open,
    {
    showModal(myModal())
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server = server)
```

In the JS console I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContent' of null
    at exports.InputBinding.getValue (<anonymous>:9:41)
    at c (init_shiny.js:117)
    at init_shiny.js:163
    at eN.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:16:18)
    at mp.c.fire (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at eN.fire (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at eN.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at mp.c.fire (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at eN.fire (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at Rp (tinymce.min.js:2)
```

Any idea of how to get around the problem?

EDIT: One further observation. In the first (working) example tinyMCE.editors contains one instance of an editor, while in the second it is empty (although the editor does display!).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this, by manually creating the TinyMCE editor (which solves the issue of the editor not appearing in `tinymce.editors`) and then use some custom JS to retrieve the value.
This seems a bit hacky to me, but it works...
Here's an example

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  header = dashboardHeader(disable = T),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  body = dashboardBody(
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js",
                referrerpolicy = "origin"))),

    # Register a custom message handler that gets the content of the editor
    # and forces update of the textarea
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('getTxt', 
        function(message) {
          var content = tinyMCE.get('tinyTxt').getContent();
          Shiny.onInputChange('tinyTxt', content);
          })"))),

    flowLayout (
      actionButton("open", "Open"),
      htmlOutput("content")
      )))

myModal <- function()
  {
  modalDialog(size = "l",
              title = "A modal dialog",
              textAreaInput("tinyTxt", "the content"),
              actionButton("ok", "OK"),
              easyClose = T)
  }

server <- function(input, output, session)
  {
  observeEvent(
    input$ok,
      {
      # Retrieve the content of the editor
      session$sendCustomMessage("getTxt", "")
      removeModal()
      })

  output$content <- renderText(       
    input$tinyTxt
    )


  observeEvent(
    input$open,
    {
    showModal(myModal())

    # Create the tinyMCE editor
    runjs("var ed = new tinymce.Editor('tinyTxt', {
        selector: 'tinyTxt',
        theme: 'modern'}, 
        tinymce.EditorManager);
        ed.render();")
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server = server)
```

Comment: For some reason it will only update the text the first time - so you have to change the id of tinyTxt each time you load a new modal.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this in 2022, this is an updated solution working with version 6 of TinyMCE. You need to get an API key which is available on registration at https://www.tiny.cloud/

I also added a print to the R console with a `delay()` as the returned input was blank otherwise.

There are a few additional options compared to the original solution. I kept them there to show how it's done. Hopefully this is useful to someone!

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  header = dashboardHeader(disable = T),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/--API-KEY-HERE--/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js",
                                    referrerpolicy = "origin")),

    # Register a custom message handler that gets the content of the editor
    # and forces update of the textarea
    tags$head(tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('getTxt', 
        function(message) {
          var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();;
          Shiny.onInputChange('tinyTxt', content);
          })")),
    
    flowLayout (
      actionButton("open", "Open"),
      htmlOutput("content")
    )))

myModal <- function()
{
  modalDialog(size = "l",
              title = "A modal dialog",
              textAreaInput("tinyTxt", "the content"),
              actionButton("ok", "OK"),
              easyClose = T)
}

server <- function(input, output, session)
{

  
  
  observeEvent(
    input$open,
    {
      showModal(myModal())
      
      # Create the tinyMCE editor
      runjs("var ed = new tinymce.Editor('tinyTxt', {
        menubar: false,
branding: false,
plugins: 'lists, table, link',
contextmenu: 'lists, link, table',
toolbar1: 'bold italic forecolor backcolor | formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
toolbar2: 'undo redo removeformat bullist numlist table blockquote code superscript  subscript strikethrough link'}, 
        tinymce.EditorManager);
        ed.render();")
    

      })
  
  observeEvent(
    input$ok,
    {


      
      
      # Retrieve the content of the editor
      session$sendCustomMessage("getTxt", "")
      
      output$content <- renderText(       
        input$tinyTxt
      )
      
      delay(500, print(input$tinyTxt))
      
      removeModal()
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server = server)
```